# When can a compiler do Return value optimization

Tags: c++, rvo

I came across rvo(Return value optimizatio) and to be honest, i have three questions about rvo.

1. In which cases must a compiler do rvo (according to the standard complient)?
2. In which cases is the compiler not allowed to do rvo (according to the standard complient)?
3. In which cases can't the compiler perform rvo?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision